How to run Liquibase Docker in Jenkins as Docker agent
I am using Windows 11 and have installed the following software on my system:

Jenkins: Version 2.479.2
Docker Desktop: Version 4.36.0 (175267)
Oracle 19c

Note: My Jenkins and Docker Desktop are running properly on my Windows system.
I recently learned that it's possible to create a Docker agent and run Liquibase directly using Docker without needing to install it on my system. I want to implement this setup by configuring a Docker agent and using it as an agent in my Jenkins pipeline script.
I installed plugins for Docker on my Jenkins which is running on local Windows:

I have been trying to configure a Docker agent for Jenkins to use Liquibase, but I'm confused by the various resources and YouTube videos. Different suggestions seem to contradict one another, and none have worked for me so far.
Here's a summary of the different approaches I came across:

Configuring in Jenkins (Declarative Pipeline settings):

Navigate to Manage Jenkins -> System -> Docker Declarative Pipeline.

Enter the Docker Label and Docker Registry URL




Configuring Docker in Jenkins Tools settings:

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Tools -> Docker Installations.

Add a Docker configuration with details like:

Docker Name
Installation Root





Creating a new agent node:

Navigate to Manage Jenkins -> Nodes -> New Node -> Cloud.
Set up the node to act as a Docker agent.







Creating a Docker template in Cloud:

Use a Docker template to define the agent environment.







For template creation, no changes have been made to the remaining properties.

Adjusting Docker Desktop settings:

Go to Docker Desktop -> Settings -> General.
Check the option: Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS.



Specifying Docker engine settings:

Some resources suggested using npipe://./pipe/docker_engine for Windows systems.
Others recommended using TCP: tcp://localhost:2375.




My pipeline script:
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'liquibase/liquibase:latest'  
            label 'docker-agent'          
        }
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Check Liquibase Version') {
            steps {
                bat "liquibase --version"  
            }
        }
    }
}

Pipeline script does not run, it shows docker-agent is offline:


Your docker-agent is offline because there are two parts to setting up an agent in Jenkins.

Add a New Node in Jenkins side
Setup at the agent side


At the moment, Jenkins Docker Pipeline plugin on the Windows host can't execute Linux Docker images due to a bug Docker pipeline: 'absolute path' error when running linux container under windows host.
Your options would be:

Setup a Linux agent with docker installed.
Although not recommended, if you cannot use a Linux agent, then setup up Jenkins using docker on a windows machine as mentioned in the documentation Setup Jenkins using Docker. Use your master as a build agent for all docker related builds.

